# Django- Can only concatenate str (not "ManyRelatedManager") to str

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save my model. But when I try to save my model I throws the following error

```
TypeError at /admin/user/teacher/add/
can only concatenate str (not "ManyRelatedManager") to str
```

My models.py file looks like this

```
class Class(models.Model):
 Class = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 section_choices = (('A','A'),('B','B'),('C','C'),('D','D'),('E','E'))
 Section = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=section_choices)

 def __str__(self):
     return self.Class + "," + self.Section

class Subject(models.Model):
subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.subject

class Teacher(models.Model):
 User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 Subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
 Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 Profile = models.ImageField(upload_to = upload_teacher_profile_to, default = 
 'defaults/teacher_profile.png')
 Class = models.ManyToManyField(Class)
 Number = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
 is_banned = models.BooleanField(default=False)

 def __str__(self):
     return self.Name + "of" + self.Class
```

Comment: What do you suppose this line `self.Name + "of" + self.Class` is supposed to do? `Class` is a `ManyToManyField` hence for an instance of `Teacher` it is a `ManyRelatedManager`. **Note:** also please don't name attributes / variables with the `PascalCase` convention, use `snake_case` See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

Updated your **Teacher** Model `def __str__(self)` function to

```py
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.Name} of {[class for class in self.Class.all()]}"
```

**Class** is a ManyToManyField in the **Teacher** Model, ManyToManyFields can contain many objects, hence you cannot use self.Class

You can learn more about ManyToManyField [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with(in class Teacher):

```
def __str__(self):
    output=""
    for x in self.Class.all():
        output=output+' | '+str(x) 
    return output
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).